# How to uninstall Battle.net and Hearthstone

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I downloaded Hearthstone and Battle.net a while ago and they had both been working great. However, I am now unable to properly log into my hearthstone account. When I do log in hearthstone is recognizing my account as a "new user", except I have the same gamer tag and gamer ID as I normally do. I have tried logging into hearthstone from other computers and it works completely fine.

I want to remove hearthstone and battle.net from my computer and reinstall them to see if it will fix this problem.

I tried using 'sudo apt-get purge Hearthstone', however this is the incorrect package name. I used 'apt-cache Hearthstone' to try to find the package name, but I did not come up with any results. I downloaded Synaptics Package Manager and searched 'Hearthstone', but also did not come up with any other results. I also tried the exact same for "Battle.net" which found the same results. I was able to find Battle.net in Synaptic Package Manager, and I "Marked it for removal", but this did not work either. Unity says that these files are still available on my computer. I can also find them using the file search tool.

So, as you can imagine I am at a loss as to how to do this. I am wondering 1) why the package names are not showing up using any of these methods, 2) if anybody has experience with Hearthstone doing this to them.

Comment: These programs are proprietary and not provided by Ubuntu, so you will have to seek support from their authors.

Comment: Could you give details about how you installed the games? To remove software via `sudo apt-get purge` you needed to have installed that software via `apt-get` or the Software Center, which I don't think you have done.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it will not be listed if you didn't install it via the apt-get.

If you installed it via a .deb package you could try using 'dkpg -l' from the terminal to list all installed .deb packages.

If you can locate it you should be able to eradicate it by typing 'dpkg -P ', which will remove the package and all configuration files.